# Any way to have UIDatePicker pick dates earlier than 1/1/1 AD/CE?

Tags: ios, nsdate, uidatepicker

I'm pretty sure the answer must be no, since if I set its minimumDate to an earlier date, it still stops rolling back at 1 AD. Also if I set its start date to a BC/BCE date it goes to 1/1/1. I'm just hoping there is some secret trick someone might know.

Answer (score 0):

Only by using a custom UIPickerView to do what you want I'm afraid...